# Extract numbers from variable with string and numeric data using R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I am trying to extract numbers from a variable in a data frame in R, which includes both numbers and text. Here is an example of the variable:

```
ID  X

1   1 sandwich 2 hamburger

2   1 sandwich 4 salad 5 soda 7 soup

3   0 chicken wings

4   n/a

5   n/a
```

I have several numbers within the text, and the numbers/text are uneven in number. I was able to extract numbers only by doing the following:

```
x_numbers <- regmatches(df$X, gregexpr("[[:digit:]]+", df$X))
```

I now have a list with these as character objects. The problem is that I need these values in the same data frame, so they are connected to the same ID (i.e. the same row). What I need is the following:

```
ID X   X2  X3  X4

1  1   2   na  na

2  1   4   5   7

3  0   na  na  na

4  na  na  na  na

5  na  na  na  na
```

Any thoughts on how best to do this so that the data is still tied to the ID and separated by column so it can be used in future analyses? I have over 3000 observations for this data. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your data:

```r
df <- data.frame(ID = 1:5,
                 X = c("1 sandwich 2 hamburger",
                       "1 sandwich 4 salad 5 soda 7 soup",
                       "0 chicken wings", 
                       NA, 
                       NA))
```

Note: if you use R>4.0 you don't need to specify `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` since it's the new default.

## Dirty but Effective

```
library(dplyr) # only with version > 1.0
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  summarise(ID = ID,
            as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, str_extract_all(X, "[[:digit:]+]") %>% 
              lapply(`length<-`, max(lengths(.))))))

#>   ID   V1   V2   V3   V4
#> 1  1    1    2 <NA> <NA>
#> 2  2    1    4    5    7
#> 3  3    0 <NA> <NA> <NA>
#> 4  4 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
#> 5  5 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

## Extra Thoughts

I would like to point out that you can still keep the information about the text if need be. [this is just to help to give you some new ideas]

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

tmp <- df %>% 
  separate_rows(X, sep = "(?<=.)(?=[[:digit:]+])") %>% 
  separate(X, c("n", "txt"), sep = " ", extra = "merge")
tmp
#> # A tibble: 9 x 3
#>      ID n     txt            
#>   <int> <chr> <chr>          
#> 1     1 1     "sandwich "    
#> 2     1 2     "hamburger"    
#> 3     2 1     "sandwich "    
#> 4     2 4     "salad "       
#> 5     2 5     "soda "        
#> 6     2 7     "soup"         
#> 7     3 0     "chicken wings"
#> 8     4 <NA>   <NA>          
#> 9     5 <NA>   <NA>
```

Given that, you get the result you need with the following code:

```r
tmp %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(x = row_number()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-txt) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = x, values_from = n, names_prefix = "X")
#> # A tibble: 5 x 5
#>      ID X1    X2    X3    X4   
#>   <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1     1 1     2     <NA>  <NA> 
#> 2     2 1     4     5     7    
#> 3     3 0     <NA>  <NA>  <NA> 
#> 4     4 <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> 
#> 5     5 <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
```

Comment: This is so great! Thanks so much Edo! Perfect fix and I used your extra thoughts code to also keep the text in my data frame. Thank you so so much!

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad the Extras were helpful. However, keep in mind that for your specific problem, @Onyambu's answer is probably the best and cleanest solution and would use his code if I were you. I left in the comments of his answer the code to get the expected output you were looking for. Instead, if you need to keep the text information like I did in the Extra Thoughts paragraph, then I suppose my solution is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

in base R, you could do:

```
read.table(text=gsub("\\D+", " ", df[,2]), fill=TRUE)

  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  1  2 NA NA
2  1  4  5  7
3  0 NA NA NA
4 NA NA NA NA
5 NA NA NA NA
6 NA NA NA NA
```

Comment: Love it. Upvoted it. To have a complete answer, would you bind it with ID? `cbind(ID = df[,1], read.table(text = gsub("\\D+", " ", df[,2]), fill = TRUE))`

Comment: Thanks Onyambu!! Love this base R version too. Had some issues running it on my end (fill=TRUE was unused and got an error that my variable had incorrect number of dimensions).

Answer (score 1):

```
my_data %>%
  mutate(x = str_extract_all(X, "[[:digit:]]+", simplify = TRUE))


  ID                                X  x.1 x.2 x.3 x.4
1  1           1 sandwich 2 hamburger    1   2        
2  2 1 sandwich 4 salad 5 soda 7 soup    1   4   5   7
3  3                  0 chicken wings    0            
4  4                             <NA> <NA>            
5  5                             <NA> <NA>            
6 NA                             <NA> <NA>
```

source data

```
my_data <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, NA),
                 X = c("1 sandwich 2 hamburger",
                       "1 sandwich 4 salad 5 soda 7 soup","0 chicken wings",NA,
                       NA,NA)
)
```

Comment: the print looks correct, but `str()` of the result will show that you just created a new column that is a matrix. I think NA_Psych needs a dataframe with separated columns.

Comment: Gotcha, lemme take another look.

Comment: Thanks Jon Spring for your help and thoughts on this!